# how to add selected value in arraylist and remove unselected value from arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, boolean

I have a 'ListView' with one button. When the user clicks on the button I added the selected position value in arraylist.But second time when user click's on the same button i want to remove this button entry from arraylist how to do this.This is my code snipet

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);


    }
    TextView msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wishdata);
    msg.setText(al.get(position));
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    final ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
    final   ImageView   iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_myImageview);
    final ListView lis = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Boolean click = true;
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<String> listOfFavoritePhrases = new ArrayList<String>();
            //check boolean value
            if (click) {
                iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thirdwish);
                /*TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
                tinyDB.putString("msg", al  .get(position));
*/            // al.add(al.get(position))

                temp.add(al.get(position));

                Log.d("ARRAY DATA", "" + temp);
                Log.d("ARRAY SIZE", "" + temp.size());

                /*ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("item",al.get(position));
                Log.d("Contentvalues",""+contentValues.toString());
                db.insert("favorite",null,contentValues);*/

                sp = context.getSharedPreferences("mypref",Context.MODE_APPEND);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("phrases", TextUtils.join(",", temp.toArray()));
                Log.d("Shared Data", "" + sp.getString("phrases", ""));
                editor.commit();
                click = false;

            }
            else {
                click = true;
                temp.remove(al.get(position));
                iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onewish);
               // db.rawQuery("delete from favorite where item like'%" + al.get(position) + "%'", null);
                Log.d("QUERY", "" + al.get(position));
                // al.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            // Toast.makeText(context, "imageview clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

Guessing by your question, I did solution like below.

Initialize **ArrayList**:

```
ArrayList<String> selectedString = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now **onClick**:

```
if(selectedString.contains(al.get(position))){
   selectedString.remove(al.get(position));
}else {
   selectedString.add(al.get(position));
}
```

Hope this will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
boolean pressedFlag = true;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now inside onClick

```
if(pressedflag){
   list.add(arrayList.get(position));
   pressedFlag = false;
}else{
   list.remove(arrayList.get(position));
   pressedFlag = true;
}
```

Hope this will help...